# How to create dependency injection for ISendEndPointProvider for MultiBus

Tags: masstransit

I currently register Masstransit for two bus controls.  I would like to inject ISendEndPointProvider for SecondBus as DI (I don't want to call GetSendEndPoint() in caller). How can I do that.  When ISendEndPointProvider always return for the first bus.

Program.cs

```
                services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.AddConsumer<FirstConsumer>();
                    x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqHost), h =>
                        {
                            h.Username(rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqUser);
                            h.Password(rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqPassword);
                            h.Heartbeat(10);
                        });

                        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqQueue, e =>
                        {
                            e.PrefetchCount = rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqPrefetchCount;
                            e.Consumer<FirstConsumer>(provider.Container);
                        });
                    }));
                });

                services.AddMassTransit<ISecondBus, SecondBus>(x =>
                {
                    x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.Host(rabbitMqOption.NotificationRabbitMqHost, hostConfig =>
                       {
                           hostConfig.Username(rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqUser);
                           hostConfig.Password(rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqPassword);
                       });
                    }));
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

When [using MultiBus](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/multibus.html#multibus-configuration), the `ISendEndpointProvider` and `IPublishEndpoint` interfaces when *outside* of a consumer will always point to `IBus`. There is no way to get the second bus without depending upon `ISecondBus`.

If the interface is used by a consumer (or a scoped consumer dependency), those interfaces will refer to the bus on which the message was received.

### Configuration Errors

Also, you should change your `.AddBus` calls to `.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg)`, which gives you proper access to the container via the *context* argument. The `AddBus` syntax will eventually be deprecated.

The correct syntax is shown below (along with a corrected consumer configuration):

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<FirstConsumer>();
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqHost), h =>
        {
            h.Username(rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqUser);
            h.Password(rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqPassword);
            h.Heartbeat(10);
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqQueue, e =>
        {
            e.PrefetchCount = rabbitMqOption.RabbitMqPrefetchCount;

            e.ConfigureConsumer<FirstConsumer>(context);
        });
    }));
});
```

Comment: Chris, Thank you so much.  What about if I would like to configure EndPoint for FirstBus . I mean how can I define the endpoint for sending a message without calling a GetSendEndPoint() and pass Uri. I would like to define the endpoint at bus set up. Can I do that ?

Comment: No, endpoints should not be kept around in that way. You _should_ call GetSendEndpoint() with the address if you want to send a message directly to an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit more for a solution that worked on my end after a couple hours of trial and error.

First, add this Nuget package: MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection,

Then, here is exactly how I'm registering MassTransit:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer(typeof(MyConsumerType));
            x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(configuration[Constants.KeyVaultSecretServiceBusConnectionString]);
                cfg.Message<IDataPrivacyEvent>(cfg => cfg.SetEntityName(MessagingConstants.DataPrivacyEndpoint));
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                cfg.UseMessageRetry(m => m.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));

                cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<IValidationEvent>(MessagingConstants.ValidationEndpoint, e =>
                {
                    e.ConfigureConsumer(context, typeof(MyConsumerType));
                    e.UseMessageRetry(m => m.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
                });
            });
        });
```